# How can i use MsSQL Where CONTAINS inside a php query with double quotes?

Tags: php, sql-server, wildcard, contains, sqlsrv

I'm trying to create a SQL query in PHP where I'm searching through the columns for search results containing a specific string with a wildcard. I'm using CONTAINS for that and I've enabled Full Text-search on the MsSQL server. Inside MsSQL Management, I can use the contains function with this query, but inside a PHP file, I can't use it because of the use of double quotes ("").

My query looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CONTAINS ((col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6), '"*$query*"')"
```

The query can't run in PHP because the double quote I'm using inside the queries CONTAINS function ('"*$query*"').

How could I escape these double quotes and be able to run this query inside a PHP file?

The only error I ran into and it doesn't really make anything clearer.

> SQLSTATE: 42000
> code: 102
> message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'.

Comment: "_The query can't run in PHP because the double quote I'm using_" I'd think it would rather be the single quotes in `'"*$query*"'`. Escape them (`\'`). Hm, do you even need the double quotes??

Comment: I will try it now. Thank you for the quick response. I will post if I know more.

Comment: @brombeer I tried using \', but it's still the same result. I found out here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-wildcards that they wanted double quotes. And it does work in the MsSQL management studio,  but not inside of PHP.

Comment: Ok,, now that you've changed your original code from single quotes to double quotes you need to escape the double quotes. `'\"*$query*\"'`, basic PHP

Comment: @brombeer Yeah that was it. Sorry, my query wasn't properly displayed. I changed it because I saw it had changed when inserted in a code block on here. Thank you very much for taking the time and for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION by @brombeer:

Had to change `'"*$query*"'` to `'\"*$query*\"'`, this helps escape the double quotes in PHP. So the query works properly now.

Working query:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CONTAINS ((col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6), '\"*$query*\"')";
```